# Meteor client-side transform collections with external data (youtube)

Tags: meteor, youtube, transform

I'm working on a multi-tenant apps. Each app will have a video module which takes several youtube playlists/channels id as input.

```
Apps = {_id: "app01", playlists:['PL4IrNZLvgtED4RTH3xCf9085hwqKmb4lM','PLlYqpJ9JE-J8QIlua0KsBIxp-VQLyM_nO']}
Apps = {_id: "app02", playlists:['id22','id23']}
```

and so on.

When user redirect to address localhost:3000/app/:_id, the app subscribe to Meteor.subscribe('apps',_id).

Now on the client side, i need to render a page that shows a list of playlists (or list of channels) with playlist's name, playlist thumbnail; and then if user clicks on the name/thumbnail, it displays another page with a list of videos belongs to that playlist/channel.

What i am doing is to have a helper to retrieve all youtube playlists's info:

```
Template.Videos.helpers({
  myPlaylist:function(){
      return Apps.findOne({}, {
            transform: function (doc){              
                playlists = doc.playlists;
                doc.date = new Date(); //for testing
                doc.videos = [];
                for (var i=0;i<playlists.length;i++){
                      console.log('find playlist: ',playlists[i]);
                      var url = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/'+playlists[i]+'?v=2&alt=json';
                      $.getJSON(url, function(response){
                        var video={};
                        video._id = response.feed.yt$playlistId.$t;                     
                        video.title = response.feed.title;
                        video.entry = response.feed.entry;
                        videos.push(video); 
                      })//end getJSON
                    }//end for
                doc.videos = videos;
                console.log('Result:', doc);
                return doc;
            }
        });
    }       
});
```

The problem is in my template, I can see myPlaylist.date as a result of transform, but I cannot see myPlaylist.videos (although I see the console.log result has data)

Does anyone has an idea how to solve this? Very appreciate!

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a response from console.log('Result:', doc) ? Because the $.getJSON function is asynchronous and should not return in time for a value to be available at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ian Jones commented, `$.getJSON` is asynchronous so `doc.videos` will never have a value where you’ve put your `console.log`. To solve this, use the [ReactiveVar package](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar):

```
Template.Videos.onCreated(function() {
  this.videos = new ReactiveVar([]);
  var self = this;
  Apps.findOne({}, {
            transform: function (doc){              
                playlists = doc.playlists;
                for (var i=0;i<playlists.length;i++){
                      console.log('find playlist: ',playlists[i]);
                      var url = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/'+playlists[i]+'?v=2&alt=json';
                      $.getJSON(url, function(response){
                        var video={};
                        video._id = response.feed.yt$playlistId.$t;                     
                        video.title = response.feed.title;
                        video.entry = response.feed.entry;
                        var videos = self.videos.get();
                        videos.push(video);
                        self.videos.set(videos);
                      })//end getJSON
                    }//end for
            }
        });
    }
});
Template.Videos.helpers({
  myPlaylist:function(){
      var instance = Template.instance();
      return instance.videos.get();
  }
});
```

Comment: @Ian &Geoffrey, I was able to see the console.log with little modification of the code (changed to var temp = Apps.find(...transform()...);

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to vote for your answer, will do so when I can!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your helps. I was unwilling to do reactive-var from the beginning, but your answer motivated me to go for it, big thanks.
This is my final code:

```
Template.Videos.created = function(){
  var instance = this;
  instance.videos = new ReactiveVar([]);
  instance.autorun(function(){
     MenusList.findOne({}, {
            transform: function (doc){  
                playlists = doc.playlists;
                for (var i=0;i<playlists.length;i++){
                      console.log('find playlist: ',playlists[i]);
                      var url = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/'+playlists[i]+'?v=2&alt=json';
                      $.getJSON(url, function(response){
                        var video={};
                        video._id = response.feed.yt$playlistId.$t;                     
                        video.title = response.feed.title;
                        video.entry = response.feed.entry;
                        var videos = instance.videos.get();
                        videos.push(video);
                        instance.videos.set(videos);
                      })//end getJSON
                    }//end for
                return doc;    
            }//end transform
        });//end findOne
  });//end autorun
}

Template.Videos.helpers({
  myPlaylist:function(){
      var instance = Template.instance();          
      return instance.videos.get();
  }
});
```